# Parsing a Complex XML file with in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing, unity-game-engine

```
- <SynchroAnimation Duration="10" EndTime="10000" ModelFileName="Lukes box (named).fbx" StartTime="0" SynchroVersion="5.2.2.0" Version="2">
- <Resource Identifier="AA67882D-9AC1-4450-90D1-2C1C7FF8F6BC" Name="Box Side - Growth" NumAnimatedInstances="1">
- <Resource3DRepresentation>
- <Entity3D Identifier="7D972BE6-9B4A-4A86-93C5-4256FB1DCE8F" Name="Basic Wall Wall-Ext_102Bwk-75Ins-100LBlk-12P [294917]">
+ <PreTransform>
  <M0>0.003280840348452</M0> 

  </PreTransform>
+ <PostTransform>
  <M0>304.799987792968750</M0> 

  </PostTransform>
  </Entity3D>
  </Resource3DRepresentation>
- <ResourceInstance>
- <VisibilityTimeline>
- <VisibilityKeyframe Interpolation="Discrete" Time="0" UseOriginal="false">
  <VisibilityValue>0</VisibilityValue> 
  </VisibilityKeyframe>
- <VisibilityKeyframe Interpolation="Discrete" Time="1822" UseOriginal="false">
  <VisibilityValue>100</VisibilityValue> 
  </VisibilityKeyframe>
  </VisibilityTimeline>
- <ColorTimeline>
+ <ColorKeyframe Time="1822" UseOriginal="false">
+ <ColorValue>
  <R>0.00</R> 
  <G>0.00</G> 
  <B>1.00</B> 
  </ColorValue>
  </ColorKeyframe>
  <ColorKeyframe Time="8066" UseOriginal="true" /> 
  </ColorTimeline>
+ <TransformTimeline>
  <TransformKeyframe Interpolation="Discrete" Time="1822" UseOriginal="true" /> 
  </TransformTimeline>
  </ResourceInstance>
  </Resource>
+ <Resource Identifier="11F593C9-5A33-4E24-A41F-7F003404E346" Name="Box Side - Fade In" NumAnimatedInstances="1">
- <Resource3DRepresentation>
+ <Entity3D Identifier="88D87801-2C5D-4F20-BBB9-21566D230A33" Name="Basic Wall 


MORE Resco
  </SynchroAnimation>
```

sn[Exported FBX XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnYuh.png)

I'm trying to get the highlighted values from the attached image XML file.  I need to get the values in "3D id" so it can be attached to the correct game object inside unity game engine with the correct metadata (i.e.: start time and date).

This is the code I currently have, but this is my first time dealing with XML files so any help would be appreciated.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;



public class XML : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string filepath = "filepath";
    public string filename = "filename";
    public string filetype = ".xml";

    void start()
    {
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(filepath + filename + filetype);

        var resourceinfo = from rescourse in xDoc.Descendants("Resource")
                           where rescourse.Attribute("Name").Value == "Growth"
                           select new
                           {

                               Resource = rescourse.Descendants("Resource").Descendants(),
                               ResourceInstance = rescourse.Descendants("Resource3DRepresentation").Descendants(),

                           };

        foreach (var rescourse in resourceinfo)
        {

            string name = rescourse.Resource.ElementAt(1).Attribute("Name").Value;
            Debug.Log(name);


        }

    }
```

Comment: Please include your XML, for easy debugging and assistance.  Otherwise, a screenshot requires hand-typing or extraction, and that's not practical for helping you easily.

Comment: `where rescourse.Attribute("Name").Value == "Growth"` -- Your screenshot shows a value of "Box Side - Growth", not "Growth". You can do `rescourse.Attribute("Name").Value.Contains("Growth")` instead if you don't want a full match, or change it to `... .Value == "Box Side - Growth"`. Also yes please don't post screenshots of text, just paste the relevant parts of the text directly into your question.